# Algorithm applied in three.js

Tags: javascript, algorithm, three.js, cartogram

In past questions had been asked about this, I understand from reading much better algorithm. This time I have developed but I have a mistake somewhere. Here's what I've been functional, they are 7 polygons and each with an assigned value (userdata.value). Apply the formula but for some reason is not working.

the desired result is something like the following:
http://prag.ma/code/d3-cartogram/#netmigrate/2011

This is the algorithm that attempts to apply (this on page 7 of the paper):
http://postimg.org/image/dvok6g9ij/

This may be more explained in the following paper:
http://lambert.nico.free.fr/tp/biblio/Dougeniketal1985.pdf
so I define each of the polygons (are 7 polygons)

```
Hexagongeometry[0] = new THREE.Geometry(); 
Hexagongeometry[0].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(3,  3, 0.0)); 
Hexagongeometry[0].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 6,  5, 0.0)); 
Hexagongeometry[0].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 9,  3, 0.0)); 
Hexagongeometry[0].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 9,  0, 0.0)); 
Hexagongeometry[0].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 6,  -3, 0.0));
Hexagongeometry[0].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 3,  0, 0.0));
Hexagongeometry[0].vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3( 3,  3, 0.0));

hexagonMesh[0].userData={value:1};  //value of polygon
hexagonMesh[0].position.set(1.5, 0.0, 4.0); 
hexagonMesh[0].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate=true;
```

Here I have applied the formula:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ks3bx3s/

Here I applied the algorithm according to my understanding.

Hopefully I can help, I really researched the solution but I can not yet.

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwvcfdge/) that shows how to compute surface area in three.js. It is not the answer to your question, but an example of how things are done in three.js. three.js supports only triangles when rendering a mesh -- not polygons.

Comment: @WestLangley ok, so I understand, I can not get the area of each hexagon? but if I make a .mesh could I?

Comment: Yes. That is what you need to do.

Comment: @WestLangley 
friend, but I if I calculate the area of each polygon with the function called "polygonArea" .. is working on if I need help with the algorithm, as z is zero, the formula used to calculate area and centroid. You could please help me with the algorithm?

Comment: You need to get the graphics working first -- then add the math to properly update the vertices. Here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7123ascw/) to help you get started.

Comment: @WestLangley I just do not understand, I can perfectly calculate the area of each of my polygons and the centroid. And this works well, can be seen in the link I posted. Apologized my ignorance.

Comment: In order to know if the algorithm is working, I think it is best to have the graphics completed first, so you can see it working. Getting the algorithm to work would be the _last_ thing you would do. Here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3dt7bwy/).... Hmmm... Now I understand why you wanted to use lines and not a mesh -- because you are only interested in the boundary points and not the interior points.

Comment: @WestLangley   http://jsfiddle.net/x3mvxmyL/    I turned my polygons to .mesh, and put the function to calculate the area. function to find the centroid would also vary ?. Now if you could please help me with the algorithm?

Comment: @WestLangley  now http://jsfiddle.net/cp6x92vc/ .  I applied the formula to calculate the area happened to me earlier in the formula. I hope that this can help me with the algorithm. the centroid would be well calculated that way?

Comment: Switched from 3D  `ExtrudeGeometry` to 2D `ShapeGeometry` to get accurate area calculation: http://jsfiddle.net/cp6x92vc/1/ .

Comment: @WestLangley friend, thank you very much, you're very kind, but if we look closely at the area gives 33, the same value that was previously before returning to .mesh polygons. Friend then either of 2 ways, the area works, I would love heart and I need help with the algorithm would be very grateful if I can help with that.

Comment: @WestLangley My problem is that the algorithm, I mean the code that would execute the cartogram not working.

Comment: I know. There is a lot to do.... See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g677eg4e/). I modified your example problem. The hexagons that are neighbors must _share_ vertices. They do now. This is important. The problem, now, is to understand the algorithm, and to update the program to modify the positions of those vertices using the correct algorithm. The function to change is `updatePoints()`.

Comment: @WestLangley Friend, you are very smart! besides very kind to help me. I see the code and see changes, I have a question, the value of the polygon can not be 0 ?, in the values of the polygon may be cases where it is 0, it would be a good idea even add 0.1 or something? (Hexagon [x] .userData.value + 0.1?). And it is important everything he has done and see the importance of doing so. But I am now at the critical point of not knowing how to apply well the algorithm.

Comment: @WestLangley As we saw in the past jsFiddle, I had an alleged implementation of the algorithm, obviously not working. Would give thousands of infinite thanks if I could help with the algorithm. sorry for my English, and excuse my ignorance on the subject of the algorithm

Comment: @WestLangley this is the code from cartogram.js...   https://github.com/shawnbot/d3-cartogram/blob/master/cartogram.js   I  tried to adapt my code, but without positive results

Comment: @WestLangley can you help  me with the algorithm? I implemented it as I understood it, and based a bit on the of d3.js, but not working.

Comment: I will do my best. Please be patient. This is a lot of work you are asking of me, and my time is limited...

Comment: @WestLangley Friend, I excuse me I'm not harassing or anything. Just add additional details that might be able to help. Obviously I understand your limited time and also take the opportunity to thank him.It is that your great help I can understand better.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d7Lzajs/) You should check it carefully.

Comment: @WestLangley  This friend was excellent! I thank you too! you are the king of all Three.js !. I am left with two questions. The first is if applying an extruded hexagons, the formula changes or work the same (the next step is to do both lines as extrusion)?. the second is:

Comment: @WestLangley on line 334, an array called "regions" is created, as I can do to not do manual that is generated dynamically, it would have serious problems because this is a simple example that I think adapt my code, and there are thousands and thousands of coordinates then get this array would not know "regions" with manual calculations. And I just saw a possible error, if I put all values to 0.1 the program (I guess this does not happen if the controls are removed) is damaged. Thank you very much! May God reward you.

Comment: 1. Why not do it like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cp6x92vc/2/), instead? Use the extruded height to represent the value? Much easier. Is this approach acceptable, instead?   2. If you want to use the cartogram with extrusion, then the algorithm and project would have to be rewritten.   3. The algorithm is a heuristic, and as mentioned in the paper, may have problems in certain cases. 4. Since you are learning, I would suggest you take the easier route and do 1.

Comment: @WestLangley 
thanks for responding quite satisfy me your help. But then I'm in big trouble, my original purpose was to make the cartogram with a figure in 3d (extruded) and functioning like the exercise he did, keeping him from enlarged or contracted. I tried to prove to the contour and then realize with extruded. he had asked about the array called regions. As I can get that table dynamically or do something similar for not doing everything so manual. (I have in my original exercise 27 polygonos with over 8,000 coordinate and make this part would manually impossible).

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you very much, you're a genius.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87044/discussion-between-westlangley-and-user5115790).

Comment: Here is the final [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d7Lzajs/1/). Now each region boundary is a simple array of [x,y] coordinates. The algorithm has been changed to accommodate the change in data structures. Good luck.

Comment: @WestLangley This algorithm can be adapted to this? http://th-mayer.de/cartogram/#population with separate vertices ?

Comment: @WestLangley I was analyzing and comparing with the algorithm that is in http://prag.ma/code/d3-cartogram/cartogram.js, would believe that not doing the last part of the paper the algorithm.

Comment: I made a notation in the code that there is no test for convergence. In other words, I did not implement "// break if we hit the target size error". Any modifications to the code will have to be made by you.

Comment: No, you cannot change the "amount", but you can re-scale the mesh. `mesh.scale.z = 2`... (also, for fun, see http://makc.github.io/three.js/map2globe/demo.html)

Comment: Ohh yeah! Thank you..!

Comment: I hope apply this algorihtm in three.js!

Comment: @WestLangley can you help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101515/geojson-draw-in-3d-js

Comment: I am not familiar with that topic.

Comment: ohhh okay. thank you..@WestLangley
I'm not giving up yet with the cartogram. if I fix the error that I have, I can export to Three.js. If you have a friend who knows of d3.js Tell please help me. thank you very much

Comment: @WestLangley  friend, you knowing too Three.js can help me with this question. ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124250/how-i-can-turn-a-figure-that-is-upside-down

Comment: @WestLangley So sorry to bother you, but taking advantage of their great knowledge...You have any idea how to fix this?...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133759/how-to-position-the-camera-in-a-specific-coordinate-three-js?noredirect=1#comment52158229_32133759

Comment: @WestLangley 
give me a few minutes of your time ?. I would like in a chat tell you about a project that I have, and then as I am new to Three.js would like to advise me and things. I'm doing a project too complex and my company makes me do it confidential, so I can not show any progress. Can you help me?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not do that, otherwise there would be 100 people waiting in line for my time... You do not have sufficient knowledge yet to do the task you have been asked to do by your boss. You need to explain to your boss that you need time to study three.js. You need to learn the basics _first_, like everyone else. I hope you understand, and good luck.

Comment: @WestLangley 
no I do not, I do not mean the algorithm. I mean to show an entire project as such. just to hear your thoughts and ideas as I improve it or something.It would be an honor for me, but I understand what you're saying.It is a work of three months with mongodb and more.

Comment: @WestLangley I make an altar and every day I light candles and you'll take flowers, if you manage to help me with this!. if this works for me, and would have ready porfin cartogram in Three.js.

Comment: @WestLangley http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196299/how-to-pass-a-map-made-in-d3-js-to-object3d-mesh-three-js

Comment: @WestLangley can you help me with this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313402/get-points-geometry-of-a-shape-in-three-js