# How I can turn a figure that is upside down?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js

I am creating a map using a json file. of d3.js to Three.js. When shown, it is shown upside down. As I can turn him?. 
I'm not sure which is the best way to flip. I want to recommend it as best he could do, since I'm new to d3 and Three.js not sure what to do.

Here you can see how it looks:

http://imgur.com/IFZ8F8h

so I need:
    http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/inciclopedia/images/b/b4/Mapamundi.png/revision/20130430135955

my code is this:

```
            mercator = d3.geo.equirectangular();
            path = d3.geo.path().projection(mercator);

            var translate = mercator.translate();
            translate[0] = 500;
            translate[1] = 0;

            mercator.translate(translate);
            mercator.scale(200);


            var data=jsonCountrys;
            var countries = [];
            var i, j;

            // convert to threejs meshes
            for (i = 0 ; i < data.features.length ; i++) {
                var geoFeature = data.features[i];

                var properties = geoFeature.properties;
                var feature = path(geoFeature);

                // we only need to convert it to a three.js path
                var mesh = transformSVGPathExposed(feature);

                // add to array
                for (j = 0 ; j < mesh.length ; j++) {
                      countries.push({"data": properties, "mesh": mesh[j]});
                }
            }

            var material= new Array();
            // extrude paths and add color
            for (i = 0 ; i < countries.length ; i++) {

                // create material color based on average   
                 material[i] =  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "#FF0000" });

            //  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    color: "#FF0000"/*, 
                    opacity:0.5*/


                // extrude mesh
                var shape3d = countries[i].mesh.extrude({
                    amount: 2, 
                    bevelEnabled: false
                });

                 var  materialSide = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: "#000000"} ); 
                           country[i] = new THREE.Mesh(shape3d, material[i]);
```

Comment: You want to rotate an image inside a canvas element or an `<img>` element? (Or any other html element)

Comment: I want rotate the map inside of the canvas (Three.js)

Comment: I never used Three.js, but try this: add `var rotate = new THREE.Euler(180, 'Y'); mercator.applyEuler(rotate);`  just after this line: `mercator.scale(200);`

Comment: thank you. 
I already did but not working.

Comment: @WestLangley  I apply this and see no changes. shape3D.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 1, - 1, 1 ) ); And the second line mark me error, where it appears a, b, c which should be placed? shape3D.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( a, b, c ) );

Comment: Sorry. I deleted the previous comment. Negative scale factors do not work well in three.js. The other alternative is to add all your meshes to a parent object (THREE.Group()), and then rotate the parent. `parent.rotation.x = Math.PI`.

Answer (score 1):

No telling what a lot of your parameters are external to this snippet, but if you create a flip matrix at the same time as you create `material` e.g.

```
var material= new Array(); // you already have this
var flip = new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(1,-1,1);
```

then apply it to `shape3d` just before calling `new THREE.Mesh()`:

```
shape3d.applyMatrix(flip);
```

That should do the trick.

*Also:* You should be careful also here, you are using `LineBasicMaterial` when really you should use `MeshBasicMaterial` and set the sides and wireframe attributes appropriately.

Comment: Applying a negative scale factor to a geometry causes problems. For one thing, winding order is reversed. Negative scale factors are generally not recommended in three.js.

Comment: Agreed about winding order, but: it looks like he wants a wireframe.

Comment: hence my original aside about using the appropriate sidedness :)